# moving div with cursor keys left and right

Tags: javascript, html, cursor, key

I'm trying to move a div element using left position. To do this i squared a div and got his element id in javascript to give it +-3pixels depending on ley strokes left and right. I've added console logs to know this stuff is working and everything is flowing accordingly, the only problem is ... IT ISNT working !!! I don't need a new code, just to understand what i'm doing wrong

The html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container"> 
            <div id="guy"> </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
        #container{background-color: teal;width: 500px;height: 500px;margin: auto; position: absolute;}
        #guy{background-color: black;width: 30px;height: 30px;}
    </style>
</html>
```

the javascript file:

```
var theMan = document.getElementById('guy');
theMan.style.position = "absolute";
xLeft = 0;
function move(e) {
    var e = e.keyCode;
    switch(e) {
        case 37:
            if (xLeft == 0) {
                console.log("Already reached the left edged");
            } else {
                console.log("Pressed LEFT");
                xLeft -= 3;
                moveGuy();
            }
            break;
        case 39:
            if (xLeft == 500) {
                console.log("Already reached the right edged");
            } else {
                console.log("Pressed RIGHT");
                xLeft += 3;
                moveGuy();
                console.log(xLeft);
            }
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Use the cursor keys idiot!");
            break;
    }
}

function moveGuy() {
    theMan.style.left = xLeft + " px";
    console.log("moving");
}

document.onkeydown = move;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space too many, replace

```
theMan.style.left = xLeft + " px";
//                          ^^ no space here
```

with

```
theMan.style.left = xLeft + "px";
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/kQaLc/)

I'll be changing my nick to "EagleEyes"

Comment: omg man, i was going totally nuts over this, thanks a million beers

Comment: @brunobliss - Happy to help, hard to spot that one.